# Why my Javascript Object properties are reset on the page as the save prompt pops up

Tags: javascript, json, prompt

I can't find out why my Javascript Object properties are reset on the page as the save prompt pops up. As I want to save them in a file.

The idea of my following script (HTML/Javascript) is to be able to save or load the color combination of the 2 displayed colored frames (red and blue, on the right).

[Here a screenshot of this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkvyO.jpg)

Here the my script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>save and load setup thru json file</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<!-- div "leftFrame" -->
<div id="leftFrame" style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:70px; width:50px; height:25px;"></div>

<!-- div "rightFrame" -->
<div id="rightFrame" style="position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px; width:50px; height:25px;" onclick="colorBlack()"></div>

<!-- button "save" -->
<form onsubmit="saveMySetupConfig('myColors.setup')">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<!-- button "load" -->
<button onClick="document.getElementById('loadMySetupConfigFile').click();">Load</button>
<input type="file" id="loadMySetupConfigFile" onchange="loadMySetupConfig(event)" style="display:none;" name="file" accept=".setup"/>


<script type="text/javascript">

// function for saving my js object "mySetupConfig" as a JSON file
function saveMySetupConfig(filename) {
    var mySetupConfigJson = JSON.stringify(mySetupConfig);  
    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(mySetupConfigJson));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);
    }

// function for loading my js object "mySetupConfig" from a JSON file
function loadMySetupConfig(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var mySetupFile = new FileReader();
    mySetupFile.onload = function(){
    var mySetupConfigJson = mySetupFile.result;
    var mySetupConfig = JSON.parse(mySetupConfigJson);
    document.getElementById("leftFrame").style.backgroundColor = mySetupConfig.leftFrame;
    document.getElementById("rightFrame").style.backgroundColor = mySetupConfig.rightFrame;  
    }
    mySetupFile.readAsText(input.files[0]);
    };


// my js object
var mySetupConfig = {};

// assign red color to a propertie of my js object and assign this propertie value to div "leftFrame"
mySetupConfig.leftFrame = "red";
document.getElementById("leftFrame").style.backgroundColor = mySetupConfig.leftFrame;

// assign blue color to a propertie of my js object and assign this propertie value to div "rightFrame"
mySetupConfig.rightFrame = "blue";
document.getElementById("rightFrame").style.backgroundColor = mySetupConfig.rightFrame;

// assign black color to a propertie of my js object and assign this propertie value to div "rightFrame" thru function colorBlack() when this div is clicked
function colorBlack(){
mySetupConfig.rightFrame = "black";
document.getElementById("rightFrame").style.backgroundColor = mySetupConfig.rightFrame;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To test if the "save" and "load" are working, I convert the blue frame to a button which become black when clicked. So that I first turn the blue frame in black and then save the color combination (red and black) to verify that it has been correctly saved, by loading the saved file afterwards.

You can test this script [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOASSA0ZE4A6) (the script has to be re-run after doing save, cause for some reason the page content disappears)

I noticed that the Javascript Object Properties of color combination are correctly saved and will be also correctly loaded.

But I don't know why the frame I turned in black become blue again when I save the color combination, although that my Javascript Object properties have been correctly saved in the file.

Does my page be automaticaly reloaded/reset after the clicking the "save" button? Why?
It doesn't behave the same way when clicking the "load" button: displayed color combination remains (until the OK button will be clicked)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Hi, I've found the problem. The "save" button was not correctly set. I replace: `<!-- button "save" -->
<form onsubmit="saveMySetupConfig('myColors.setup')">
<input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>`  with `<!-- button "save" -->
<button onclick="saveMySetupConfig('myColors.setup')">save</button>` and now it works properly.

Comment: You can check it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FOHMGY4AF4V3)